# How to know current mask

Tags: c

In bash, `umask` with no arguments returns current mask.
Is there a way to do the same in C?

`umask(mode)` in C changes the mask to mode and returns the previous mask. I would like to have a function that immediately returns the current mask.

Comment: [The umask manual](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/umask.2.html) says: "*It is impossible to use umask() to fetch a process's umask
       without at the same time changing it.  A second call to umask()
       would then be needed to restore the umask....Since Linux 4.7, the umask of any process can be viewed via the
       Umask field of /proc/[pid]/status.  Inspecting this field in
       /proc/self/status allows a process to retrieve its umask without
       at the same time changing it.*" So you can write your own function to parse `/proc`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to do the same in C?

I've got some bad news for you, you can't do it in C. But, then again, you can't really do it in `bash` either :-)

The `bash` shell itself uses the "change it then quickly change it back" method for getting it, which you can also do from your own C program:

```c
mode_t umask_arg;
umask_arg = umask (022);  // get it while temporarily setting.
umask (umask_arg);        // change it back quickly.
                          // umask_arg now has the umask.
```

Other than my added comments, that's directly from `builtins\umask.def` (which creates the file to eventually be compiled for the `umask` built-in) in version 5.1 of the `bash` shell.

Comment: @walter, if you spend any time looking at the `bash` internals, you soon stop worrying about whether you're writing "dirty" code :-)

Answer (score 3):

Here is an example of how it can be done from the GNU documentation:

```c
mode_t
read_umask (void)
{
    mode_t mask = umask (0);
    umask (mask);
    return mask;
}
```